# how to crawl a website page when it is fully loaded(js, css all loaded)

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I would like to crawl some websites page like Amazon or eBay to get the sold item pictures path. When I checked the page, it seems like the image src is modified by javascript when page completely loaded.

There is one library called `cheerio`. it is simple but it doesn't expose a method to do some check after page completely load and it only returns html back. Does anyone have the experience on this? or is there any library i can use to get the real image path since it is modified by javascript? thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try with puppeteer: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: Can you post the code, where you're having this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, puppeteer is probably the best way to scrape dynamic pages. It's a node library that interfaces with chrome/chromium and will load the page just like an instance of regular chrome.

Inside your `page.evaluate`, you can use the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) browser api to watch the DOM and wait for the images you want.

I've had good experiences using [Apify](https://www.apify.com/docs/actor), which will run puppeteer instances for you and has a generous free tier.